# Is there a way to generate a git patch of secret files (some files listed in .gitignore) so that I can apply these patch later or in other computer?

Tags: git, encryption, patch, git-diff, git-apply

I would like to generate a patch (using git diff) of secrets files or folders in the .gitignore file that I won't versioning so that I can easily configure an entire project on another friend's computer just cloning the project and applying these patch (using git apply).

If this is possible I can encrypt it using gpg and email it. These secret files might be certificates, passwords, directory trees, or any other file that would be sent in a normal commit if it wouldn't be in the .gitignore file.

I tried generating this patch file using git diff in many ways, but by default, it didn't work. I don't know if it's possible, but it sure would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

As these files are ignored, the repository database doesn't hold their history versions. But if you have two copies of files, no matter if they are tracked by a git repository or not, you can use `git diff --no-index $patha $pathb` to generate the diff from the version of patha to the version of pathb.

For example, to compare `/path/to/foo/` and `/path/to/bar/`,

```
git diff --no-index /path/to/foo /path/to/bar
```

To compare `/path/to/foo/a.txt` and `/path/to/bar/a.txt`,

```
git diff --no-index /path/to/foo/a.txt /path/to/bar/a.txt
```

To compare `/path/to/foo/a.txt` and `/path/to/bar/b.txt`,

```
git diff --no-index /path/to/foo/a.txt /path/to/bar/b.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. If a use ```git diff --no-index /dev/null /path/to/bar/a.txt``` I can create a patch of the ```a.txt``` file's creation.